# Microsoft Web Platform Installer -- Intended for production use?

Tags: windows, web-platform-installer

Web PI seems to make it very easy to install popular open-source apps and keep it up-to-date, even if based on a non-MS software stack (like Wordpress).

Given I'm only familiar with the Microsoft stack (IIS, ASP.NET, MSSQL etc.), and not PHP, is it a good idea to take a small virtualized Windows Web Server instance, and use Web PI to set up a public installation of say Wordpress and its dependencies like PHP etc.? Does it follow common practices concerning security, stability etc.?

Or is this only intended for developer machines and I better let someone with a better understanding of PHP do a "hardened" manual setup?

I should add that no other software would be deployed on this VM, so I'm not afraid about Web PI messing with my custom IIS configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe MS intends for these to be used in Production environments.  My experience so far is they work well, but of course, depending on your use case, you may need to know more about the app or a more specialized install.  Also, you'll likely need to do a bit of work if you need to scale to large workloads (load balancing, centralized db, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it and it worked like a charm so far. I hope it won't be defaced any time soon ;-)